# Mixed model with 4 levels of data

Tags: r, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I have time series data at weekly level with 4 levels.

- Level 0 - Time Week on week
- Level 1   Job type - Day,Night etc
- Level 2   Location - Location to which job belongs
- Level 3   County - County under which location falls

Population data is available at location level. unemployment data is available at county level.
I am trying to predict the Weekly applications (Y) based on wage rate , population in the location, and unemployment rate. There are other factors but not mentioning all .

I have created below model:

```
   model = lmer((applications)~wage rate + population + unemployment_rate_+ (1+wage rate+ population +unemployment_rate |county/location/Jobtype) , 
             REML = TRUE,
             data = data4)
```

Would like to confirm if this structure of the model makes sense? .

I am also confused on how we calculate the prediction at week level. Couldn't find any example where such 4 levels of time series data Analysed. Most of the examples are math oriented I am unable to follow it .

Please advise.
[image]